# How to download "Split" CSV files from H2O DAI?

Tags: split, driverless-ai

I notice the new function of "Split" in the "Dataset" menu, which is quite wonderful.
How can we download the newly generated CSV files from this "Split" function ?
I tried 'find' in the server directories, but I see that the split csv files are stored in the server NOT in plain texts.

/opt/dai-1.5.4-linux-ppc64le/tmp# find . -name atec_anti_fraud_test1*
./fuhilapa/atec_anti_fraud_test1.1557095335.9342732.bin

/opt/dai-1.5.4-linux-ppc64le/tmp# file ./fuhilapa/atec_anti_fraud_test1.1557095335.9342732.bin
./fuhilapa/atec_anti_fraud_test1.1557095335.9342732.bin: data

/opt/dai-1.5.4-linux-ppc64le/tmp# head -n 2 ./fuhilapa/atec_anti_fraud_test1.1557095335.9342732.bin
JAY1@▒▒@▒▒@▒▒@▒▒@▒▒@▒▒@▒▒@▒▒    @       ▒       ▒
@

Answer (score 2):

This is not a currently available option for DAI 1.6 and lower, but the functionality should be added in a future DAI release.